# SCP issue with multiple files - UNIX

Tags: unix, ssh, scp

Getting error in copying multiple files. Below command is copying only first file and giving error for rest of the files. Can someone please help me out.

Command:

```
scp $host:$(ssh -n $host "find /incoming -mmin -120 -name 2018*") /incoming/
```

Result:

```
user@host:~/scripts/OTA$ scp $host:$(ssh -n $host "find /incoming -mmin -120 -name 2018*") /incoming/
Password:
Password:
2018084session_event 100% |**********************************************************************************************************|  9765 KB    00:00
cp: cannot access /incoming/2018084session_event_log.195-10.45.40.9
cp: cannot access /incoming/2018084session_event_log.195-10.45.40.9_2_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command uses *Command Substitution* to generate a list of files. Your assumption is that there is some magic in the "source" notation for scp that would cause multiple members of the list generated by your `find` command to be assumed to live on `$host`, when in fact your command might expand into something like:

```
scp remotehost:/incoming/someoldfile anotheroldfile /incoming
```

Only the first file is being copied from `$host`, because none of the rest include `$host:` at the beginning of the path. They're not found in your **local** `/incoming` directory, hence the error.

Oh, and in addition, you haven't escape the asterisk in the `find` command, so `2018*` may expand to multiple files that are in the login directory for the user in question. I can't tell from here, it depends on your OS and shell configuration.

I should point out that you are providing yet another example of the classic [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem. Special characters WILL break your command. The "better" solution usually offered for this problem tends to be to use a `for` loop, but that's not really what you're looking for. Instead, I'd recommend making a `tar` of the files you're looking for. Something like this might do:

```
ssh "$host" "find /incoming -mmin -120 -name 2018\* -exec tar -cf - {} \+" |
tar -xvf - -C /incoming
```

What does this do?

- `ssh` runs a remote `find` command with your criteria.
- `find` feeds the list of filenames (regardless of special characters) to a `tar` command as options.
- The `tar` command sends its result to stdout (`-f -`).
- That output is then piped into another `tar` running on your local machine, which extracts the stream.

If your `tar` doesn't support `-C`, you can either remove it and run a `cd /incoming` before the `ssh`, or you might be able to replace that pipe segment with a curly-braced command: `{ cd /incoming && tar -xvf -; }`

The curly brace notation assumes a POSIX-like shell (bash, zsh, etc). The rest of this should probably work equally well in csh if that's what you're stuck with.

Limited warranty: Best Effort Only. Untested on animals or computers. Your milage may vary. May contain nuts.

If this doesn't work for you, poke at it until it does.

Comment: Thanks ghoti ! but facing another issue now. 
1. Actual path on remote server is "/export/home/wlsadmin/scripts/OTA/incoming/" and it creates the complete directory structure in my local machine and inside that it copies the files.
2. in my local machine, tar supports -C but still it's not copying the files. I used the alternate you recommended. (curly-braced command)

Comment: To strip components of the longer path, you may have a `--strip-components` option for tar. Check the man page on your system. (I see it in FreeBSD, macOS and Linux.) Alternately, you could `cd` before `find`. Something like: `ssh "$host" "cd /export/.../OTA/incoming && find ./ ...`